# Wrap existing layout element in another layout with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

When designing activity layouts, I frequently encounter cases where I need to wrap an existing element in a layout. For an example, say I have following layout structure.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView />
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to wrap one of the TextViews in another LinearLayout to get following.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView />
        <SomeNewElement />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this, preferably through the Android Studio designer?

Comment: I worked a lot with JavaFX, i can tell SceneBuilder (with all it's caothic bugs) it's miles better than Android Studio XML Editor and Visual Studio XAML. Hopefully they will add wrap and unwrap features for layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your can drag your new layout from the Element list (Palette) into the Component Tree (as a child of the top-level layout).

Then you just have to drag and drop your textView into the new layout.

Comment: It's pretty hard to drag an element to an empty layout I'd rather do it in XML editor.

Comment: You mean (for example): drag your textView into the new (empty) layout? It's a classic drag and drop... Can't be easier.

Comment: Now I get it. I was trying to drop the text view into layout shown in the preview. I should use Component Tree instead :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may easily customize your own wraps.

Press `Ctrl+Alt+S` to get to Settings. Navigate to `Editor>Live Templates>surround`. I use surround here by way of example, but you can navigate to the most logical section for you. You'll see a few examples already there for you. Please note the use of the wildcard, `$Selections`, which represents the entirety of the code you'll wrap.

Now click the plus icon to your right in the settings pane to begin adding your own. In the lower half of the dialog, you'll enter your context in the Template Text area, with the keyboard shortcut key sequence you prefer. Please also note the `Applicable in...` change link that provides programming-language options specific to your desired wrap.

This nifty feature allows you to provide shortcuts in specific context, which won't interfere with other languages you may be programming - they could be using the same shortcuts.

Click `Apply` for edits. You may also duplicate, right-click and select `Move` if you'd like to add it to another collection heading within Live Templates. When you're done, click the `OK` button.

Back in Android Studio code line editing, while code to be wrapped is selected, pressing `Ctrl+Alt+T` immediately displays the context menu to select the enclosing coding you've provided for, with its shortcut.

Additionally, a valuable quick tip from StackOverflow's Ali Nem (link below) shows pressing `Ctrl+W` a couple of times in editor conveniently selects the entire code block. You'll find out that it works much better in comparison with "mousing" your selections.

See: [Shortcut to select a line of code in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41541803/823321)