# Shortcut to select a line of code in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Is there a short cut to select one line of code in android studio?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> will select all the text from the current caret position to the beginning or end of the current line. (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> on mac). You can also **triple-click** on the required line to select it wholly. This can also be achieved by **clicking on the line number**.

If you want to copy/cut an entire line then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> after placing the caret on the required line will do.

They have more useful shortcuts [here](http://lifehacker.com/5321432/how-to-highlight-text-like-a-keyboard-ninja).

Answer (score 23):

You might also use CTRL + W several times.

Comment: Thank you! That's the one I've been looking for but didn't know how to put it in google

Comment: looking for that. using ctrl+w then ctrl + c improve my keyboard efficiency.

Comment: For OS X users, this is Option+Up

Answer (score 10):

There is <kbd>`Command`</kbd> + <kbd>`C`</kbd> that will copy the entire line. But if you are like me and you don't want to pollute your clipboard history with line selections, you can try this solution. (<kbd>`Command`</kbd> +  <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`V`</kbd> to view clipboard history)

1. Go to Android Studio Preferences
2. Go to `Keymap`
3. Expand `Editor Actions`
4. Scroll down to `Select Line at Caret`
5. Assign any key command you want to it. I used <kbd>`Command`</kbd> +  <kbd>`L`</kbd>, but it is up to you.

Answer (score 6):

Try using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

This should select *and* copy the entire current line.  Note that it won't work if you already have some text selected.  In that case, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> would behave as usual, copying the text selected only.

I should note that I based my answer on that Android Studio is built off the IntelliJ platform, and so most shortcut keys are probably the same between the two.

Reference: [Select current line in intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572403/select-current-line-in-intellij)

Comment: Have to wait for 2 minutes...@Divins answer is better.. I'll upvote you as this also solves the problem

Answer (score 4):

For Windows:

1. <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`End`</kbd> (from cursor to line end)
2. <kbd>`Shift`</kbd> + <kbd>`Home`</kbd> (from cursor to line start)
3. Triple click on a line

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Classic UI, you can select a line by clicking the line number on the left margin of the editor. You can select multiple lines by clicking and dragging over the numbers.

In New UI, clicking the line number creates a breakpoint by default. The same functionality as the Classic UI can be achieved by following this procedure:

1. Press `Ctrl+Shift+A`
2. Type `Breakpoints Over Line Numbers`
3. Disable

As described in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-ui.html#gutter.

In this mode you can create a breakpoing by clicking in the empty area just to the right of the line numbers.